# Proof of true or false statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Deciding whether this is true or not. I believe the statement is true just based of the definitions of what $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ mean. But I'm not sure how to prove this.

> For any sets A and B, if $(A \cup B)$ \ $(A \cap B ) = ∅$ , then $A = B$

Comment: What is \ between intersection and union of A and B?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare. set theoretic difference

Comment: @JaideepKhare The first set without the second set; all elements belonging to the first set, but not to the second set.

Comment: If $X \setminus Y = \emptyset$ then $X \subset Y$. (Can you prove that) so $A\cup B \subset A \cap B$.  What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by Contradiction:

Assume $A \not = B$

Then either there is something $x$ in $A$ that is not in $B$, or vice versa, but either way $x$ will be in $A \cup B$ but not in $A \cap B$, hence $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) \not = \emptyset$. Contradiction!

Comment: Does this make the statement true hence you use proof by contradiction ?

Comment: You seem to be a beginner in maths. There are two methods of proving something: direct (as you can see in my answer) or by contradiction (as the ones above). So, yes, the proof is valid.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp yep I am :/

Comment: @rprogramr If you are unfamiliar with the proof by contradiction technique, you should definitely read up on it (just google and tons of resources will show up!). Anyway, the basic idea is that to prove something is true, you show that the assumption that it is false leads to contradiction (hence, you effectively show that it is impossible for it to be false ... and so it should be true ... in classical logic at least ...)

Comment: @Bram28 Ahh yes I see i just read about it now :) thanks ! be my tutor haha !

Comment: The proposed answer involves a common **dumb and unnecessary** decision to do a proof by contradiction: if $(A \cup B) \mathrel{\backslash} (A \cap B) = \emptyset$,, then any element of $A$ must also be an element of $B$ and vice versa, so $A = B$.  So just use the standard approach for proving an equality between sets.

Comment: @RobArthan Once you assume $x \in A$, wouldn't you need to do a (very small) proof by contradiction to show that $x \in B$?

Comment: That is not really a proof by contradiction but rather a proof by contrapositive.
Where should the small proof by contradiction in the direct argument be? If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup B$, by assumption $x\in A\cap B$ (using Modus Tollens), so $x\in B$.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Right, that's what I meant .. modus tollens can be seen as a very little proof by contradiction.  Many proof systems do not have Modus Tollens, nor Contrapositive, and so you would need to use a proof by contradiction. Anyway, whether it's proof by contradiction, contraposituive, or modus tollens, at *some* point you need to reverse direction in this proof (it's not a 100% direct proof that you Modus Ponens your way through), and I figured that doing the reversal at the outset would result in a pretty intuitive proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume that $A \neq B.$ Without loss of generality assume that there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \notin B.$ Show that $A \cup B \setminus A \cap B$ cannot be empty, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \cup B \setminus A\cap B = \emptyset$ implies there are no elements of $A\cup B$ that are not in $A\cap B$.  So $A\cup B \subset A\cap B$.    So if there is any element in either $A$ or $B$ then it is in $A$ and $B$.

So any element in $A$ is in $B$ and any element in $B$ is in $A$.  Any any element not in $A$ can't be in $B$ either and vice-versa.  So $A = B$.

Or more formally:

If $a \in A\cup B$ then $a \not \in A\cup B \setminus A \cap B$ so $a \not \in (A \cap B)^c$ so $a \in A \cap B$ so $A\cup B \subset A \cap B$.  But $A \cap B \subset A$ and $A \cap B \subset A$ so $A \subset A \cup B \subset A\cap B \subset B$ and $B \subset A \cup B \subset A \cap B \subset A$.  So $A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\emptyset = (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B) = ((A\cup B)\setminus A)\cup((A\cup B)\setminus B) = (B\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B).
$$
Therefore, $B\setminus A = A\setminus B = \emptyset$.

You get $A = (A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B) = A\cap B\;$ and

$B = (B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B) = A\cap B$.

Comment: Who downvoted without comment? Coward! ;o)

Comment: Upvoted for fairness

Comment: Upvoted for thankfulness. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $(A \cup B)$ \ $(A \cap B ) = \emptyset$.

Let $x \in A$.
Then $x \in A \cup B$ and so $x \in B$ (otherwise $x$ would be in $(A \cup B)$ \ $(A \cap B )$, which we have assumed to be empty). So every member of $A$ is a member of $B$. Likewise, every member of $B$ is a member of $A$. So $A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

usually we define $$ A\Delta B:= (A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)\,\,( \text{ Symmetric Difference})$$ by [**CLIC**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182359/proving-equality-of-sets/2184052#2184052) we can prove that $$ (A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)=(A \cup B)\setminus (A \cap B) $$ In addition we know, by [**Symmetric Difference of Equal Sets**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1951185/66744), that $$A=B \leftrightarrow  A \Delta B=\emptyset$$ therefore your statement is obviously true